# how do I convert unix string to proper datetime format in python

Tags: python, datetime, unix, unix-timestamp, tableau-api

I have a unix string. And want to display that in tableau date format which expects 5 arguments

```
import dataextract as tde
from datetime import datetime

tdefile=tde.Extract('USCSVExtract.tde')
tableDef.addColumn('CreationDate', tde.Type.DATE)

date_object = datetime.strptime(story.CreationDate, '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.Z')
newrow.setDate(3,date_object)
table.insert(newrow)
tdefile.close()
```

value of story.CreationDate is 2014-10-31T20:02:36.622Z

I am unable to figure out T20:02:36.622Z this part

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the milliseconds part:

```
datetime.strptime(string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

Comment: *whispers* and also the `T` character

Comment: And also the `T` character.

Comment: Still it is giving error- TypeError: setDate() takes exactly 5 arguments (3 given)

Comment: newrow.setDate(3,datetime.strptime(story.CreationDate, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))

Comment: What does the method signature look like? My guess is that you don't want to pass it a `datetime` object, but the year, month, and day integers. I.e. `newrow.setDate(3, date_object.year, date_object.month, date_object.day)`